# Django TypeError when creating objects in a model using dictionary

Tags: python, django, dictionary, django-models

I'm trying to pass the items of a dictionary into a model, each key, value pair to be an object.

```
d1 = {'Alex': 3.0, 'Chriss': 7.42, 'Robert': 9.13}
```

This is the model:

```
class Team_one(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    score = models.FloatField(default=0.0)
```

When I'm trying to do an example in the shell, I'm getting a type error

This is the example:

```
x = {'Alex': 3.0}
Team_one.objects.create(**x)
```

or

```
m = Team_one(**x)
m.save()
```

This is the error:

```
`TypeError: 'Alex' is an invalid keyword argument for this function`
```

Comment: I think the issue is straightforward. You should try to understand what unpacking of dictionary means .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your model class `Team_one` doesn't have a property `Alex`.

In your dictionary you need the keys `name` and `score` with values **Alex** and **3.0**.

Eventually you can convert the dictionary you retrieve into a list of dictionaries:

```
team_one = [{'name': name, 'score': score} for name, score in d1.items()]
```

This is the output you'll get:

```
[
    {'score': 7.42, 'name': 'Chriss'},
    {'score': 3.0, 'name': 'Alex'},
    {'score': 9.13, 'name': 'Robert'}
]
```

Now you can iterate through the list and create the objects.

Answer (score 2):

Yeah surely you get a TypeError because you are using a dictionary just for your values. A dictionary represents a key-value storage, so in your case you have to specify the keys and the values for them:

```
{
    'name': 'Alex',
    'score': 3.0,
}
```

If you want to create more than one object you can use just a for loop:

```
team_ones = [{'name': 'Alex', 'score': 3.0}, {'name': 'Chriss', 'score': 7.42}, {'name': 'Robert', 'score': 9.13}]

for team_one in team_ones:
    Team_one.objects.create(**team_one)
```

Comment: ok, but how can i make the dictionary that way when it's returned from other function like this: {'Alex': 3.0, 'Chriss': 7.42, 'Robert': 9.13} ?

Comment: This is simple, in short term you could use:
    
    return_value = {'Alex': 3.0, 'Chriss': 7.42, 'Robert': 9.13}
    your_preferred_value = {name: key, score: value for key, value in return_value.items()}

Answer (score 2):

This should work:

```
for key, value in d1.items():
    Time_team.objects.create(name=key, score=value)
```

And it uses your initial `d1` dictionary.

Comment: Now it's working. It's is a very straightforward solution, too.

Answer (score 2):

**TL:DR;**

You should change your dictionary to match your model:

```
x = {
   'name': 'Alex',
   'score': 3.0
}
Team_one.objects.create(**x)
```

---

**Explanation**

When you are creating a django object, the create function expects `**kwargs` that will match the model. In your case, the correct call to `create()` would be:

```
Team_one.objects.create(name='Alex', score=3.0)
```

When you are *"unpacking"* your dictionary (`**x`), what happens is that the key is passed as the argument's name and the value as the arguments value. What you initially did, resulted in this **erroneous** call to `create()`:

```
Team_one.objects.create(Alex=3.0)
```

So by changing your dictionary to the following form, you can "unpack" it correctly in the `create()` function:

```
arguments = {
    'name': 'a_name',
    'score': 2.0
}
```

**EDIT due to comment:**

What you should do, is to:

1. Either change how your function returns your dictionary
2. Or reform your received dictionary to match the above
3. Or call the `create()` without "unpacking" anything:

   ```
   for item in d1.keys():
       Team_one.objects.create(name=item, score=d1[item])
   ```

Comment: ok, it works, but what can i do when my dictionary is returned in another function like this d1 = {'Alex': 3.0, 'Chriss': 7.42, 'Robert': 9.13} ?

Comment: I have added an edit to jump start you @NitaAlexandru .

Comment: Very elaborate answer, especially the summary after the edit. Unfortunately I can upvote only once.

Comment: @cezar thanks :) yours is short and at the point, which is also great!